# Symfony set a env/global variable based on database value

Tags: php, symfony, symfony6

I have different, azure blob containers in a single storage account, and when a user tries to add a file I need to decide the container that file should go to based on a database value, and I do not want to get the storage container value everywhere in the application

As a solution subscribing to `KernelEvents::REQUEST` and `ConsoleEvents::COMMAND`, I have created a new env variable like below.

```
putenv('AZURE_CONTAINER=my-container-name');
```

I'm not sure if it is the best way to handle the case, is there any other better way to handle the case?

Comment: Why do you need to set an environment variable or a global variable? If the change is per-request, making it a global variable does not immediately appear to make a lot of sense, looks like it's a "domain" concern better resolved at runtime directly, not an infrastructure concern that should affect the whole application. It's difficult to advise on a "good way" to do this, since the only requirement so far is "write to an environment variable" (which looks suspect).